How to not respond to didSelectRowAt when adding single and double click UITapGestureRecognizer on UITableViewCell
I added UITapGestureRecognizer for single and double clicks on UITableViewCell, and let the single click gesture be responded to when the double click gesture fails, but I don't want the tableView's didSelected to be responded to. Is there any way to handle this in the TableViewCell class?
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let dataSource = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
    
    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let view = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero)
        view.dataSource = self
        view.delegate = self
        view.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCell.description())
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.view.addSubview(tableView);
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        dataSource.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.description(), for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
            return cell;
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        40
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         
    }
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        let singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
        singleTapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false;
        addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)
        
        let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTap))
        doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)
       
        singleTapGesture.require(toFail: doubleTapGesture)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @objc func tap() {
        
    }
    
    @objc func doubleTap() {
        
    }
}

I want only tap and doubleTap to be called in case of single and double click, but didSelectRowAt is not called

It's not entirely clear what you mean when you say you don't want "didSelected to be responded to" ...
If you don't have a didSelectRowAt function, the default is to do nothing, so it's "not responding" to it.
If you don't want the cell to highlight, in cellForRowAt you can set:
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.description(), for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell;
}

The table view will still internally track that a row is selected, but there will be no visual indication, and if your code does not implement didSelectRowAt there won't be a "response."
If you want to prevent the table view from tracking the selected row, you can implement shouldHighlightRowAt:
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

Now, you don't need cell.selectionStyle = .none and didSelectRowAt will never be called.
